# How to listen to graphic environment or device changes in java

Tags: java, graphics, listener

In java one can get the current graphics environment using

```
GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
```

and than loop through the devices using

```
GraphicsDevice[] screenDevices = graphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices();

for (int i = 0; i < screenDevices.length; i++) {
    GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice = screenDevices[i];
    ...
}
```

But the number of `GraphicDevice`s can change at runtime, e.g. by plugging in an USB-monitor. Or the user can change a `GraphicsDevice`'s resolution or move it relative to another graphics device if there are multiple monitors.

How can I listen to changes of the `GraphicsEnvironment` and the `GraphicDevice`s?

**EDIT**

I tried to implement the change detection using a daemon thread that inspects the graphics environment at a specific interval, but it doesn't work.

It doesn't work because the `GraphicsEnvironment` is hold in a statc variable and initialized only once.

Also the sub classes of `GraphicsEnvironment` cache the `GraphicDevice`s. So new `GraphicDevice`s will only be detected if the jvm process is restarted.

Comment: You can't really.  You might be able to setup a low priority thread that peeked at this settings and sent out an alert, otherwise you'd need to investigate a JNI/JNA solution

Comment: I also thought that I have to go this way. I will try a daemon thread and update my question after I tested it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer an own daemon thread will not work. I updated my question. Maybe I try the JNI way... if so I will come back and hopefully provide an answer :)

Comment: Although it is not about "listening" for changes, something like this could be built based upon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912360/graphicalenvironment-does-not-update-screen-devices-after-switching-off-second-s/26913495#26913495

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be to batch the execution of an small java program, that just stores the last known graphics environement in a file and execute the notification whenever it changes (execution should be instant, mostly the cost of running the jvm).

It's not elegant, but doing something the native way would need to be cross-platform and would end up ugly too. Unless you don't care about portability.

Choose your poison.