# Why Java graphicsenvironment can and cannot update unplug monitor changes?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I'm using java graphics environment to detect monitor changes, it can detect correctly when unplugged an extended monitor ( run with a simple class ).

But in my company project. It can't update monitor correctly when I unplugged an extended monitor ( it show correctly when I ran applet with 2 monitors first times). When I unplugged and ran it again, it showed 2 devices with wrong devices in the second data. ( I use latest jre 8 both )

I found this is the same issue with me.

[How to listen to graphic environment or device changes in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802784/how-to-listen-to-graphic-environment-or-device-changes-in-java)

[GraphicalEnvironment does not update screen devices after switching off second screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912360/graphicalenvironment-does-not-update-screen-devices-after-switching-off-second-s/26913495#26913495)

So I don't understand why it can and it can't when update plugged monitors.

I try with declare new instance. But my company project was down when re-login.

Could you give me any solution.

Simple code for detect

```
GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
```

enter code here

Comment: What is it? Can it? Or can't it? It cannot be both, so what are you asking? --- How is that code detecting anything?

Comment: It appears your question is identical to the questions to which you’ve linked, except that you are asking “why is it like this” which is not answerable by anyone outside of the AWT development team.

Comment: I can detect Graphics Device correctly when I unplugged monitors ( ran on simple class ). But in my company project it can not update Graphics Device correctly.

I don't know the different exactly. Here it's a different.

1. run on my machine with simple class with java 8

2. run on company project but deployed on server and run by called from html. (java 8 too ).

Comment: what screen should it detect when run/deployed on a server that likely has no monitor connected to it?

Comment: First it can show data correctly no matter how many monitors i plugged. But when i unplgged it or added it. It show same data as first show. The monitor which add or remove was not update to it.